# How to create a TStringList descendant with Owner that will auto free the TStringList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm hoping to create something like a "TOwnedStringList" (class name is a fiction) that I could construct as:

```
sl := TOwnedStringList.Create(Self);
sl.Sorted := True;
sl.Duplicates := dupIgnore; 
sl.Add(...);
// etc...
```

Where `Self` could be a Form (for example), so that the Owner will auto free the StringList.
I want to be able to avoid calling `sl.Free` myself.

Is This possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's going to be a little messy. You'd need to do something like this.

```
type
  TOwnerComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FOwnedObject: TObject;
  public
    constructor Create(Owner: TComponent; OwnedObject: TObject);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TOwnedStringList = class(TStringList)
  private
    FOwner: TOwnerComponent;
  public
    constructor Create(Owner: TComponent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

{ TOwnerComponent }

constructor TOwnerComponent.Create(Owner: TComponent; OwnedObject: TObject);
begin
  inherited Create(Owner);
  FOwnedObject := OwnedObject;
end;

destructor TOwnerComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FOwnedObject.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{ TOwnedStringList }

constructor TOwnedStringList.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create;
  if Assigned(Owner) then
    FOwner := TOwnerComponent.Create(Owner, Self);
end;

destructor TOwnedStringList.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FOwner) and not (csDestroying in FOwner.ComponentState) then
  begin
    FOwner.FOwnedObject := nil;
    FOwner.Free;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Basically you create an instance of `TOwnerComponent` that is owned by the `Owner` that you pass to `TOwnedStringList.Create`. When that `Owner` dies, it destroys the `TOwnerComponent` which in turn destroys your string list.

The code is resilient to an explicit `Free` being called on the string list.

Comment: Looks promising. Should the TOwnerComponent constructor be created with `reintroduce` directive? Also, How can I protect the `TOwnedStringList` against `sl.Create(nil)` and explicit `sl.Free`?

Comment: `Create(nil)` is fine. That just means, no owner, let me take charge of ownership. Or if you don't want that, then raise an exception. Explicit `Free` will take a little more thinking about. Bear with me.

Comment: How about `if Assigned(FOwner) and not (csDestroying in FOwner.ComponentState)`?